# Setup Airport Express on a Separate Network

Tags: wireless-networking, router, subnet

The company I work for recently purchased an airport express. They want the network from the Airport Express separate from the internal LAN network. Basically, none of the networks should have access to each other and the Airport Express should be a different subnet than the LAN.

I set the configuration to Bridge Mode in the Airport Utility to bypass the DHCP and made sure I updated the settings. However when I do an ipconfig, I still notice the wireless network is in the same subnet as our LAN.

What's the best way to go about this? Is this even possible with the Airport Express?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By putting the express into bring mode you've added it to the network you currently have. Remove it from bridge mode and set it to "create new network." You also do want it to serve DHCP to clients unless your users are all connecting to it through static addresses.

Comment: So the only other options under the Wireless tab are either DHCP only or DHCP and NAT. Both don't seem to work for my situation. I'm getting a Double NAT error message. Any thoughts yman?

Comment: Select DHCP and NAT. You can ignore the double NAT message(it's ok because you're running two separate networks here), it should let you create the network anyways.

Comment: Hey yman, so I was able to get onto the Internet in a different DHCP range. Unfortunately, I'm still in the same subnet and I can still access our company's LAN. Maybe some context might help. We'll be renting out space in our office to some new recruits and we want to keep them separate from the employee network. However, we still want these new recruits to access the company printer. Like a VLAN situation which is separate and in no way connected to the employee network. Is that possible? Thanks again

Comment: @B.Ng, You need to create a different network (VLAN) to connect your device. This happens on the company router and switches. You then connect the WAP to the new network as a bridge. You must do the restrictions with ACLs in the router. You can prevent this new network from accessing anything but the printer with an ACL.

Comment: Much appreciate it Ron. What you said makes sense and thinking about it, I can see how the OSI reference model comes to play. The only thing I'm not sure about is where to begin. Do I need to login to the firewall, router, and all switches manually to set the changes? Also, would I need to configure the DHCP server? What framework would you use if you were me?